# How do I list the properties of an entityset?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

How can I list the properties that an entityset has at runtime?

Comment: Do you mean the the entities?

Comment: Just call GetProperties on the entity type...

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to get the entity given I only have the context and the name of the entity?

Comment: for example if I use EntitySet es =container.GetEntitySetByName("customer",true ); the es object does not have a GetProperties() method

Comment: I am a little further I am now doing the following Type entityType = entity.GetType(); foreach (var property in entityType.GetProperties()) { Console.WriteLine(property.Name);}

However I am not getting what I expect

Comment: Got IT!
EntitySetBase es = container.BaseEntitySets.OfType<EntitySet>().Where( eb=>eb.ElementType.Name ==s).FirstOrDefault();
             
 foreach (EdmMember memberinfo in es.ElementType.Members.Where(m=>m.BuiltInTypeKind == BuiltInTypeKind.EdmProperty) )

Comment: Put it as an answer to your question please.

Comment: Hi @Ladislav I am new and dont know how to mark an answer, or maybe i dont have that right yet. I cant see any link to mark an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer link.  The answer is

```
EntitySetBase es = container.BaseEntitySets.OfType<EntitySet>()
    .Where( eb=>eb.ElementType.Name ==s).FirstOrDefault(); 
foreach (EdmMember memberinfo in es.ElementType.Members.Where(m=>m.BuiltInTypeKind == BuiltInTypeKind.EdmProperty) )
```